# Spring Security SAML assertion expiry with Application Session Expiry

Tags: angularjs, session, spring-security, saml-2.0, spring-saml

I'm getting confused with the SAML assertion expiry vs Application session expiry.

In simple words, when we have an application deployed in a container, there is a session created. This session expiry can be controlled with the below entry in web.xml

```
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>60</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

Moving on, when I have Spring Security with SAML extension, obviously the same session concept applies. (I'm deploying the application in WildFly 8.2, if that matters)

Further, when the application session expires, the logout behaviour seems to be equivalent to Local Logout concept.

So far so good. Now lets say that the  SAML assertion is good for 2 hours and the user has been actively working for 2 hours. What should happen to the subsequent request then? Should it re-login to the IDP? But, wouldnt that be inconvenient to the user? If the application redirects to IDP for logging in again after 2 hours of assertion expiry, How should AJAX requests be handled?

This is in reference to [the question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26047854/handling-saml-redirects-on-ajax-requests)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Spring SAML issues an `ExpiringUsernameAuthenticationToken` for authenticated users. The token starts returning false in its `isAuthenticated()` method once the SAML Assertion used to authenticate the user reaches its `sessionNotOnOrAfter` time.

This behavior can be disabled by overriding `SAMLAuthenticationProvider` and changing method `getExpirationDate(credential)`, which returns time when the Assertion expires, or `null` in case it never does. Application will then fully rely on session expiration configured in the container.

Once the `ExpiringUsernameAuthenticationToken` expires, Spring Security will pass the current token to the `AuthenticationManager` (configured in securityContext.xml under `<security:authentication-manager>`).

You can affect what happens next, by adding your own `AuthenticationProvider` able to handle the `ExpiringUsernameAuthenticationToken`. Otherwise system fails with `ProviderNotFoundException` or some other `AuthenticationException` like `BadCredentialsException` (in case you're using username/password authentication at the same time).

The exception is subsequently handled by `ExceptionTranslationFilter`, which start new authentication process by invoking the configured authentication `EntryPoint` - e.g. `SAMLEntryPoint` which either starts authentication with default IDP or displays IDP selection page. The process will also essentially perform local logout, as you say.

System by default behaves the same for all HTTP calls - AJAX or not. You can define different behavior by splitting your API and normal URLs into separate `<security:http>` elements and use different `EntryPoints` (interface `AuthenticationEntryPoint`) for each. For example `Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint` might be suitable for your AJAX calls.