# Spring MVC detect ajax request

Tags: ajax, spring, spring-mvc

How to detect an ajax request in the best possible way?

I'm currently using this in my controller:

```
private boolean isAjax(HttpServletRequest request){
    String header = request.getHeader("x-requested-with");
    if(header != null && header.equals("XMLHttpRequest"))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

But I don't like this way, I think there should have a better solution with Spring.

Comment: Can you add to your question as why you want to do it at high level, there are more chances of getting better solutions...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

That is the only "generic" way to detect an Ajax request.

But keep in mind: that's not failproof, it is just a *best effort* attempt, **it is possible to make an Ajax request without sending the `X-Requested-With` headers**.

jQuery usually includes that header. Maybe another lib doesn't. The protocol certainly doesn't consider that header mandatory.

---

Just a note: Your code is perfectly valid, though you could write it a bit simpler:

```
private boolean isAjax(HttpServletRequest request) {
    String requestedWithHeader = request.getHeader("X-Requested-With");
    return "XMLHttpRequest".equals(requestedWithHeader);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple bullet proof solution. Simply send query parameter like ajax=1 from your ajax request and send a different value or do not send this parameter for regular request and check in your controller and take action accordingly.